# How make an image fit an entire JQuery DataTable cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

A rather straightforward problem here, but unfortunately I cannot seem to find an answer on the DataTable docs or on StackOverflow.

I am trying to **make an image fit the entire cell of my JQuery DataTable**. To be more precise, I am trying to make my image take up the space occupied by the green arrows in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

I have tried a few solutions such as using `cellspacing="0"` and `cellpadding="0"`, as well as using my browser's inspector to activate/deactive some css elements linked to the table but nothing changed the padding inside the cell.

Here is my JS code where the table is populated and the columns specified:

```
var table_dom = $('#table');
self.table = table.DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    dom: "<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-md-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-md-5'i><'col-md-7'p>>",
    ajax: self.callUrl(),
    columns: [
        {
            data: 'id',
            name: 'id',
            title: 'ID'
        },

        // ... some columns

        {
            data: 'some_data',
            render: function (data) {
                image = "<img src='http://www.dvd-ppt-slideshow.com/images/ppt-background/background-1.gif'/>";
                return image ? `<div title="${data}" class="case-thumbnail aw-tooltip admin-tooltip">${image}</div>` : '';
            },
            name: 'some_image',
            title: 'Image',
            orderable: false
        },

        // ... more columns
    ],
    order: [[0, 'desc']],
    responsive: true,
    pageLength: 10
});
```

And here is my HTML code with the container for the table:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-data table-responsive responsive" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"></table>
</div>
```

Any solutions are welcome. The ideal solution would be affecting only the cells of that column, but if the solution affects all the cells that would work too.

Cheers guys.

---

**Edit 1**:

Following @Andrei Gheorghiu's solution of using `background: url('path/to/image') no-repeat center center /cover;` in a class, is there is a way of doing this using **only the style attribute in my render function**? I am asking because the image is different for each row and I therefore need to assign it dynamically for each cell instead of defining it in its own css class.

Here is the code I have so far, which doesn't display an image at the moment. I believe this is due to the fact that the styling is being applied to the `<div>` inside the cell instead of the `<td>` element. So is there a way of aplying the styling to the `<td>` element directly from my JS code?

```
self.table = table.DataTable({
    // ... table settings
    columns: [
        // ... some columns
        {
            data: 'some_data',
            render: function (data) {
                image = getImgUrl();
                return image ? `<div title="${data}" class="class1 class2" style=" background-image: url('${image}') no-repeat center center /cover"></div>` : 'No image';
            },
            name: 'some_image',
            title: 'Image',
            orderable: false
        },
        // ... more columns
    ],
    // ... table settings
});
```

---

**Edit 2**:

I've gotten a bit further and found that of course if the `<div>` is empty the background won't be displayed. So I tried a few things such as using `width: '100%'; height: '100%';` and adding `&nbsp;` to the div's contents. I can now get the background to display but it still doesn' take the entire screen:

JS (return from the `render` function):

```
return `<div title="${data}" class="class1 class2" style="width: '100%'; height: '100%'; background: url('http://www.dvd-ppt-slideshow.com/images/ppt-background/background-1.gif') no-repeat center center /cover;)">&nbsp;</div>`
```

Screenshot:

[image: second screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to cover an element with an image you do not use `<img>`.
You use [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image):

```
.yourBgImgClass {
  background: url('path/to/image') no-repeat center center /cover;
}
```

It will cover the element with the image cropping from either top+bottom or left+right equally, without breaking the image aspect ratio.

Comment: Not at all, @joe. It's required.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thansk for the solution I hadn't thought about that. But do you think there is a way of doing this using only the `style` attribute in my `render` function? I am asking because the image is different for each row and I therefore need to assign dynamically instead of defining it in its own css class. I have updated my question if needed.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu oh i meant the slash :) is that a IE8-defensive measure or something?

Comment: @joe I know what you meant. It's standard CSS. Why not check [the docs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background)?

Comment: @AdamJaamour, you can set the common properties (`background:transparent no-repeat center center /cover`) in CSS and only pass the `background-image` using `style` individually. A stylesheet is simply a place where you can put CSS instead of placing it in `style`. But if the latter makes more sense to you, it's working.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I understand that, if I could I would put everything in the css but I can't because I need my background img to be dynamically loaded for each cell as it is different for each row. So I tried your recommendation and doesn't really work as the image doesn't take the whole cell just a portin of it (see screenshot). I created a class where I put `.orr-img {background: transparent, no-repeat center center /cover;}` and use the class in my `div` as follows: `class="orr-img"`. I then specified the background url in the `style` tag as follows: `style="background-image: url('path');"`

Comment: You probably need some negative margins to make up for some paddings. I can't help you without a [mcve].

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thx for the suggestion I'll try fixing this issue and let you know when I find something